# Reading alphabetic characters using OLEDB in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, excel, asp.net-mvc, oledb

I am trying to read Excel file in asp.net using OleDb.

First same code was used for excel file, which have only numbers in it and this was working.
But the excel file now is changed, so I have some alphabetic characters in the fil and I am not able to read this kind of text.

```
 String sConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source="+userMappingExcel+";Extended Properties=Excel 8.0;";

            OleDbConnection objConn = new OleDbConnection(sConnectionString);

            objConn.Open();

            OleDbCommand objCmdSelect = new OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM UserMapping", objConn);

            OleDbDataAdapter objAdapter1 = new OleDbDataAdapter();

            objAdapter1.SelectCommand = objCmdSelect;

            DataSet objDataset1 = new DataSet();

            objAdapter1.Fill(objDataset1, "XLData");

            DataTable table = new DataTable();

       
            DataView d = objDataset1.Tables[0].DefaultView;
            foreach (DataRowView rowView in d)
            {
                DataRow row = rowView.Row;
                if (row.ItemArray[0].ToString() == "20320_anbab_caa")
                {
                    
                       //Some logic
                }

            }
```